# Tree view on Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am quite new to Cocoa framework in terms of both language and framework. What is the equivalent class for creating a Tree view on Mac OS X. I am trying to port an UI on Mac OS X. In this, a tree view is used to store some names and names under them. They are being set by a function provided by me (say AddItemUnder).

How to create tree view on Mac OS X? I saw NSOutlineView. But that requires some data source. In my case, I do not have any data source.

Also, in my case, only UI related will be in Objective-C. Rest code will be in C++ and may be common for both Windows and Mac OS X.

Currently, I need tree-view where I can add items like a hierarchical tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my case, I do not have any data source.

If you don't have any data, what are you going to display on OSX GUI?

I would say you certainly have a data that is called Model, and you use GUI for the View part, and to bind Model with View you need a Controller. You are given a controller called NSTreeController.

If you are not happy with TreeController, then you can go for NSMutableDictionary and go on to add objects under objects upto any level.

Something like this :

```
@"World":@"worldKey"    
     -@"Asia":@"asiaKey"
           -@"India@":@"indiaKey"
                 -@"Bangalore:@"bangaloreKey"
           -@"@"Japan":@"japanKey" 
     -@"Europe":@"europeKey"   
           -@"England":@"englandKey"
                 -@"OldTrafford":@"oldTraffordKey"
     -@"Australia":@"australiaKey"
           -@"NewSouthWales:@"newSouthWalesKey"
```

Comment: Means, I do not have any data prior to creation of Tree View. Data will be added later when user will call the function.

Comment: yes, obj-c based in KVC and even TreeViewController uses KVC-KVO to form KVB. If you dont have any idea before then at runtime you can surely create a data-structure of your own.

Comment: I am quite new to Cocoa. What is KVC, KVC-KVO and KVB?

Comment: Key Value Coding, Key Value Observing and, Key Value Binding.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html

Comment: What I need some control of equivalent of TreeView of Win32. Is it that much complex in Cocoa?

Comment: there is an easy one called NSTreeController. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTreeController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: As i have also worked on VB6, there we have listview and treeview, I can understand your doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Finally, I created a treeview using NSOutlineView and my own data source class. How can I add data dynamically after NSOutlineView being rendered?